# phpmyadmin blank page ( nginx ) (ubuntu xenial) (php 7)

Tags: php, ubuntu, nginx, phpmyadmin, server

I have installed phpmyadmin and symlinked it.But when i goto hostname/phpmyadmin it returns a blank page with phpmyadmin icon on titlebar.

I have tried many solutions but not able to find whats the problem :(

server config:

```
 `  server {
   # listen 80 ;
   # listen [::]:80 default_server;

    # SSL configuration
    #
     listen 443 ssl default_server;
     listen [::]:443 ssl default_server;
    #
    # Note: You should disable gzip for SSL traffic.
    # See: https://bugs.debian.org/773332
    #
    # Read up on ssl_ciphers to ensure a secure configuration.
    # See: https://bugs.debian.org/765782
    #
    # Self signed certs generated by the ssl-cert package
    # Don't use them in a production server!
    #
    # include snippets/snakeoil.conf;

    root /var/www/laravel/public;

    # Add index.php to the list if you are using PHP
    index index.php  index.html index.htm index.nginx-debian.html;

     server_name example.com ;

    ssl on;
    ssl_certificate /etc/letsencrypt/live/example.com/fullchain.pem;
    ssl_certificate_key /etc/letsencrypt/live/example.com/privkey.pem;


    location / {
            # First attempt to serve request as file, then
            # as directory, then fall back to displaying a 404.
            try_files $uri $uri/ /index.php?$query_string;
    }

    # pass the PHP scripts to FastCGI server listening on 127.0.0.1:9000

    location ~ \.php$ {
                                include snippets/fastcgi-php.conf;

    #       # With php7.0-cgi alone:
    #       fastcgi_pass 127.0.0.1:9000;



    #       # With php7.0-fpm:
            fastcgi_pass unix:/run/php/php7.0-fpm.sock;
    }

    # deny access to .htaccess files, if Apache's document root
    # concurs with nginx's one
    #
    location ~ /\.ht {
            deny all;
    }
            location ~ /.well-known {
            allow all;}


 }


# Virtual Host configuration for example.com
#
# You can move that to a different file under sites-available/ and symlink that
# to sites-enabled/ to enable it.
#
server {
       listen 80;
#       listen [::]:80;
#
     server_name example.com;
#
#       root /var/www/example.com;
#       index index.html;
#
#       location / {
#               try_files $uri $uri/ =404;
#       }

     return 301 https://example.com$request_uri;
}
```

`

Comment: Did you check the various error logs (system, nginx, php if applicable)? What is the exact HTTP response code that the browser's developer tools display?

Comment: @BurninLeo one error is : `Failed to load resource: net::ERR_INCOMPLETE_CHUNKED_ENCODING`

Comment: I have seen such problems when the output is compressed either by PHP or by NGINX or (worse) by both. To track down the error, I recommend disabling output compression for a while. You may also try to run the PHP script from the command line, using PHP. This separates PHP issues from NGINX issues.

Comment: @BurninLeo how do i disable output compression?

Comment: PHP (via setting, there's another option via ob_start()): http://php.net/manual/en/zlib.configuration.php, nginx: https://www.nginx.com/resources/admin-guide/compression-and-decompression/

Comment: @BurninLeo tnx for the links. compression in php was already disabled.In nginx,i have set `gzip off` from `gzip on` in nginx.conf file. Restarted nginx ,still the same error :(

Comment: Okay, the try to other: Run the script from the console, using `php`. Also create a simple test file `<?PHP echo "Hello"; ?>` in the phpmyadmin directory and try running this in the browser. Doing these two things should give you a good idea where the error is located.

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/133787/discussion-between-yash-chaudhary-and-burninleo).